# how to refactor the following codes

Tags: java

I have a method want to refactor, and some dummy codes as below:

```
if(deletedInfo.isEmpty() && addedInfo.isEmpty()) {
    // some logic codes
} else if (!deletedInfo.isEmpty() && addedInfo.isEmpty()) {
    // some logic codes
} else if (deletedInfo.isEmpty() && !addedInfo.isEmpty()) {
    // some logic codes
} else if(!deletedInfo.isEmpty() && !addedInfo.isEmpty()) {
    // some logic codes
}
```

is there a appropriate pattern or some algorithm to refactor this codes?

Thanks.

Comment: Is `//some logic code` completely different in each condition?

Comment: I don't like any of the solution proposed. Probably because need more context information. 
Maybe refactoring the structure of data... doesn't make sense deletedInfo and addedInfo at all, does it? If is not deleted should be added. If you want check if nothing happens (not added, not deleted) then probably your object structure would be empty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (deletedInfo.isEmpty()) {

    if (addedInfo.isEmpty()) {
        // some logic codes
    } else {
        // some logic codes
    }

} else {

    if (addedInfo.isEmpty()) {
        // some logic codes
    } else {
        // some logic codes
    }

}
```

Comment: You can also put the lines inside the outer `if` and `else` into a private method and call it instead. Will be invaluable especially if the logic is many lines long.

Answer (score 2):

You can refactor with this code:

```
int val = 0;
if (deletedInfo.isEmpty()) val |= 0x1;
if (addedInfo.isEmpty()) val |= 0x2;

switch (val) {
    case 0: // some logic codes
    case 1: // some logic codes
    case 2: // some logic codes
    case 3: // some logic codes
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways you could do it. Here's one:

```
if (a) {
  if (b) {
    // do J
  } else {
    // do K
  }
} else {
  if (b) {
    // do L
  } else {
    // do M
  }
}
```

You might prefer something more akin to a truth table, particularly if you have more than two tests to combine:

```
int switcher = 0;
if (a) switcher|=1;
if (b) switcher|=2;
switch(switcher) {
  case 0:
    // do J
    break;
  case 1:
    // do K
    break;
  case 2:
    // do L
    break;
  case 3:
    // do M
    break;
}
```

I don't think there is an automatically "right" way - you have to choose whatever is clearest for your situation.

Comment: I wouldn't go with the switch-approach. Looks like a hack to me.

Comment: I agree it's not so straightforward at first glance - but I wouldn't rule it out automatically, there may be situations where it's warranted.

Comment: Terse is what we are looking for, isn't it? BTW @AlexeiKaigorodov, | instead of + is a better choice for me, since we are dealing with a bit field.

Comment: yes, actually I also thought the switch approach, but this is a very hack way. and the first approach maybe is the first things that come to mind.